# Merge one to many relation table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables

Header table,

```
Id Name  Value
1  Test1 Value1
2  Test2 Value2
```

Comments table,

```
Id Comments comments_type CREATE_DTE 
1  Testing   CLOSE         03/15/2017
1  Testing   RESEARCH      03/15/2017
1  Testing2  CLOSE         03/17/2017
2  Testing3  CLOSE         03/12/2017
2  Testing4  RESEARCH      03/16/2017
```

Now i have written a aggregate query for comments table to merge rows based on the ID.

```
SELECT LISTAGG(COMMENTS, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CREATE_DTE DESC) 
FROM COMMENTS_TBL GROUP BY ID
```

But how to join these 2 table and get below desired output,

```
ID Name   Value  CLOSE_Comments    Res_COMMENTS
1  Test1  value1 Testing2 ;Testing  Testing
2  Test2  value2 Testing3           Testing4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find below the updated query. Since you have changed the requirement i have made changes to include the new column on top of the old query itself.

**UPDATE** Replace `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to handle no comments scenario

```
SELECT HEADER_TBL.ID
    , HEADER_TBL.NAME
    , HEADER_TBL.VALUE
    , CLOSE_TYPE.CMTS CLOSE_CMTS
    , RESEARCH_TYPE.CMTS RESEARCH_CMTS
FROM HEADER_TBL 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT ID
        , LISTAGG(COMMENTS, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CREATE_DTE DESC) CMTS
    FROM COMMENTS_TBL
    WHERE COMMENTS_TYPE = 'CLOSE'
    GROUP BY ID
) CLOSE_TYPE
    ON HEADER_TBL.ID = CLOSE_TYPE.ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT ID
        , LISTAGG(COMMENTS, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CREATE_DTE DESC) CMTS
    FROM COMMENTS_TBL
    WHERE COMMENTS_TYPE = 'RESEARCH'
    GROUP BY ID
) RESEARCH_TYPE
    ON HEADER_TBL.ID = RESEARCH_TYPE.ID;
```

Comment: it works, but it brings the values in multiples. i just need 2 rows of data, but it brings 4X2, 8 rows data

Comment: @Pat I tried this query with your sample data and it returned only 2 records.

Comment: Apologizes, i forgot to add another column. There is a comment type, which needs to be included in aggregate condition. Could you add this in your answer?

Comment: @Pat I have made changes for your requirement. Please check

Comment: one more thing i just noticed, it does not bring the header table values if no comments found. Because of inner join, so i changed to left outer join, but now the problem is the same comment is fetched for all rows. Am i using the correct join?

Comment: @Pat I have changed the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to handle the case where there are no comments available in the `COMMENTS_TBL`